# How to consume a FixedDocument from a background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

The following code works correctly when everything is on the same thread. However, in moving the PrintPreview to the UI thread when the FixedDocument is made on a background thread, I get:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it."

The problem line is:

```
writer.Write(fixeddocument.DocumentPaginator);
```

I could not get Dispatcher.invoke/begininvoke -- or anything else to solve this problem.

So how can a FixedDocument from another thread be brought to the UI thread?

(Please note, the FixedDocument takes several minutes to generate so must be created on the background thread. And Yes, I have Googled for hours and not found any solution. If there is one, I missed it).

I keep thinking that I will have to keep the PrintPreview in the same thread as the FixedDocument--I hope not.

```
// Print Preview
public static void PrintPreview(FixedDocument fixeddocument, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Was cancellation already requested? 
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
          ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    using (Package p = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        Uri u = new Uri("pack://TemporaryPackageUri.xps");
        PackageStore.AddPackage(u, p);

        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p, CompressionOption.Maximum, u.AbsoluteUri);

        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

        writer.Write(fixeddocument.DocumentPaginator);

        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        var previewWindow = new PrintPreview(fixedDocumentSequence);

        Action closeAction = () => previewWindow.Close();

        ct.Register(() =>
              previewWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(closeAction) 
        );

       previewWindow.ShowDialog();  

        PackageStore.RemovePackage(u);
        doc.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was obviously the `static` modifier in your method. Changing it to an instance method allow you to facilitate `Dispatcher`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    // Print Preview
    public void PrintPreview(FixedDocument fixeddocument, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Was cancellation already requested? 
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (Package p = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            Uri u = new Uri("pack://TemporaryPackageUri.xps");
            PackageStore.AddPackage(u, p);

            XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p, CompressionOption.Maximum, u.AbsoluteUri);

            XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

            //writer.Write(fixeddocument.DocumentPaginator);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<DocumentPaginator>(writer.Write), fixeddocument.DocumentPaginator);

            FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

            var previewWindow = new PrintPreview(fixedDocumentSequence);

            Action closeAction = () => previewWindow.Close();

            ct.Register(() =>
                  previewWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(closeAction)
            );

            previewWindow.ShowDialog();

            PackageStore.RemovePackage(u);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke did not compile. Using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke lead to "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".  What now? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne, try placing `PrintPreview` in a `System.Windows.Window` class. I suppose you had removed `static` modifier.

Comment: @BodDust Yes ...I refactored this to take PrintPreview back to the main thread and removed the static modifier. I'm not sure what you mean by "placing the PrintPreview in a System.Windows.Window". Example??

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see the point of creating an empty window with class MainWindow only to create a second PrintPreview window? (i.e., PrintPreview is a window which is using the DocumentViewer as the primary element to display the fixedDocumentSequence)...unless you mean to move the DoceumentViewer to the MainWindow and have it grab the fixeddocument from the background thread as its content??? Even keeping the PrintPreview in the main UI thread causes issues when the fixeddocument came from another thread "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

Comment: @AlanWayne, that was an example. I didn't mean creating an empty window. You probably would like to define a `WindowBase` and place `PrintPreview` within that class. Then any call to `PrintPreview` should be done from a class inherits from `WindowBase`. Besides the issue accessing `FixedDocument` from thread other than the one owns it, you would need to check if the thread creates `FixedDocument` is a STA thread.

Comment: ...Yes. FixedDocument is being constructed from framework elements--which require an STA Thread. It takes several minutes to create the FixedDocument, which is why it is on a background STA thread. All works well as long as the PrintPreview is also done on that same backgroung thead.  Moving PrintPreview to the UI thread is where I get the problems.

Comment: @AlanWayne, if you were using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` calling `PrintPreview`, you would need to make that task run from `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. Btw, the `PrintPreview` method can be refactored into `PrintPreview` window so that it can be called, for example, `new PrintPreview().Open(fixedDocument, cancellationToken)`